# How to create function for providing before/after submit event in JavaScript based on jQuery?

Tags: jquery

First, I love a concept of jQuery about handler event. Please look at the following code.

```
$('#someid').submit(function()
{
    // some logic for checking input data before submit
    return isValid($(this));
});
```

But I have some problem when I try to create some indicator for displaying submit process. Because jQuery has not any function like before/after xxx event. So, it’s impossible to create some process like the following diagram.

[Flow Diagram http://qmv6sa.bay.livefilestore.com/y1pybXwRr2DP061WcFlJCQppOJnwmSvT_CBcON53vyKJ-bvmQAMd6npqOm9VjorNRoqY2eUYt9mVCtEL_HArowjUtWRVEnwFu4J/flow.PNG](http://cid-f093f24662880947.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/StackOverFlow/flow.PNG)

Although it’s possible to create the above diagram, but in real-world application 3 functions in different events do not know each other. So, it’s impossible to create some function like the following code.

```
function form_submit()
{
    if(isValid($(this)))
    {
        // send form data via AJAX/POST
        submitForm($(this));

        // display animation
        displayAnimation();
    }
    else
    {
        displayError();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea for solving this question?

**Update#1**

I like some thing like the following code.

```
// Before Submit function will receive function as parameter. If some function return false this submit will not be submitted.
$('#form1').beforeSubmit(function()
{
    return isValid($(this));
});

// So, I can create custom submit function for posting data via AJAX or any protocal.
$('#form1').submit(function()
{
    var serializedData = serializeForm($(this));
    $.postForm($(this), serializedData);

    $(this).afterSubmit();
    return false;
}

// After that, I can display animation for showing form process.
$('#form1').afterSubmit(function()
{
    displayAnimation($(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve my question with event wrapper by using the following code. It's quite long code. But it works well on my basic testing. I can assign prepare submit event for watermark extender, before submit event for control validator, submit event for sending form data via AJAX and after submit event for form posting indicator.

```
/* jQuery - Form Submit Event Extender */
var _prepareSubmitFunction = new Object();
var _beforeSubmitFunction = new Object();
var _submitFunction = new Object();
var _afterSubmitFunction = new Object();
jQuery.fn._oldSubmit = jQuery.fn.submit;

function formSubmitEventExtender_Init(form)
{
    form = $(form);

    form.unbind('submit.formSubmitEventExtender');
    form.bind('submit.formSubmitEventExtender', null, function ()
    {
        form.prepareSubmit();

        if (form.beforeSubmit())
        {
            var result = true;

            for (var i in _submitFunction[form.attr('id')])
            {
                var temp = _submitFunction[form.attr('id')][i]();
                temp = ((temp === false) ? false : true);

                result = result && temp;
            }

            form.afterSubmit();

            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

jQuery.fn.prepareSubmit = function (fn)
{
    var x = $(this);
    x.ensureHasId();
    var id = x.attr('id');

    if (fn)
    {
        if (!_prepareSubmitFunction[id])
        {
            _prepareSubmitFunction[id] = new Array();
            formSubmitEventExtender_Init(x);
        }

        if ($.inArray(fn, _prepareSubmitFunction[id]) < 0)
            _prepareSubmitFunction[id].push(fn);
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i in _prepareSubmitFunction[id])
        {
            _prepareSubmitFunction[id][i]();
        }
    }

    return x;
};
jQuery.fn.beforeSubmit = function (fn)
{
    var x = $(this);
    x.ensureHasId();
    var id = x.attr('id');

    if (fn)
    {
        if (!_beforeSubmitFunction[id])
        {
            _beforeSubmitFunction[id] = new Array();
            formSubmitEventExtender_Init(x);
        }

        if ($.inArray(fn, _beforeSubmitFunction[id]) < 0)
            _beforeSubmitFunction[id].push(fn);
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i in _beforeSubmitFunction[id])
        {
            if (!_beforeSubmitFunction[id][i]())
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    return x;
};
jQuery.fn.submit = function (fn)
{
    var x = $(this);
    x.ensureHasId();
    var id = x.attr('id');

    if (fn)
    {
        if (!_submitFunction[id])
        {
            _submitFunction[id] = new Array();
            formSubmitEventExtender_Init(x);
        }

        if ($.inArray(fn, _submitFunction[id]) < 0)
            _submitFunction[id].push(fn);
    }
    else
    {
        x._oldSubmit();
    }

    return x;
};
jQuery.fn.afterSubmit = function (fn)
{
    var x = $(this);
    x.ensureHasId();
    var id = x.attr('id');

    if (fn)
    {
        if (!_afterSubmitFunction[id])
        {
            _afterSubmitFunction[id] = new Array();
            formSubmitEventExtender_Init(x);
        }

        if ($.inArray(fn, _afterSubmitFunction[id]) < 0)
            _afterSubmitFunction[id].push(fn);
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i in _afterSubmitFunction[id])
        {
            _afterSubmitFunction[id][i]();
        }
    }

    return x;
};
```

Comment: can you post the code for ensureHasId too please, it's not there and it doesn't seem to be a standard javascript or jquery function

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is not to do this as a "normal" submission at all but use a method of Ajax submission. There are several of these. Check out [Form Submission ajaxSubmit()](http://be.twixt.us/jquery/formSubmission.php).

Assuming you make another Ajax call to validate the form somehow (or, say, retrieve additional information from another site) you could follow this process:

1. User clicks "submit";
2. Disable the submit button;
3. Make an Ajax call to validate, retrieve extra information or whatever;
4. In the callback for the completion of this Ajax call, call ajax submit;
5. When that submit returns send the user to a new page or do whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do something like:

```
function beforeSubmit() {
    if (isValid($(this)) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/form/submit',
          success: afterSubmit
      });
    }
    return false;
}

function afterSubmit() {
}
```

Comment: If you never care about an error in the request, you can alternatively just use $.get or $.post, the callback for those will be called after the response is returned.

Comment: As I say, you can't fix logic for submit event. Because I don't sure how many function in before submit or after submit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using Panels. But I would love to solve it using ajax as well.